# R devtools: create both html and pdf of vignettes

Tags: html, r, pdf, r-markdown, vignette

I have written a tutorial in vignette form for one of my packages.

It works fine, but it only creates the html version of the vignette. Is there a way I can create both the html and the pdf version of my vignettes?

I have tried to append rmarkdown::pdf in the output field of my .Rmd file, but it didn't work.

Comment: Add all the formats you want to the YAML header (with the "default" one being the first) and do `rmarkdown::render("YOUR_RMD_FILE", "all")`

Comment: how do I add them? In the output field, I do I set two formats?

Answer (score 10):

This is what I added in the header of my vignette.

```
output:
  knitr:::html_vignette:
    toc: true
    css: custom.css
    fig_caption: yes
  pdf_document:
    highlight: null
    number_sections: yes
```

and the I used the command from [hrbrmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1457051/hrbrmstr) above which produces a PDF file.

```
rmarkdown::render("vignettes/itkr.Rmd", "all")
```